# VegaJs - How to attach an event listener to bar graph legends?

Tags: vega

I have a requirement, on clicking a legend I have to update the data table based on the selected legend. I need to apply the selected legend as a filter for my data table. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Vega view supports event listeners

```js
// define the view
_v = new vega.View(vega.parse(spec))
     .renderer('svg')
     ...

// listen to events
_v.addEventListener('click', function(event, item) {
  // event is the event listener
  // item is the active scenegraph
  console.log('CLICK', event, item);
})
```

if you want the text of the clicked legend item for the data table, use: `item.text`

Reference: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_addEventListener